# Excel vba macro how to create an empty Range variable object

Tags: vba, excel

As the question says, how to create an empty range variable object:

tested with the code below it cannot insert a new cell/range from a different source (workbook/worksheet).

```
Public Sub test()

Dim Sheet As Worksheet    
Dim t As Range    
Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)    
Sheet.Activate    
Set t = Sheet.Range("A1:A1")    
t.Delete    
t.Insert   

End Sub
```

the above code gives me the object required exception. How do we create an empty Range and populate it with cells from another source or at least a custom made cell to be inserted in the Range?

similar to how an array object is capable or in a gridview where we can create a row/column/cell object instantiate it and give values to it and add it to gridview, like how you do it in asp.net/c# winforms?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Do you want to take Range('A1:B20') in worksheet A and put them in worksheet B, erasing any content that was in worksheet B before?

Answer (score 1):

After you have deleted a Range you cannot refer to it because it does not exist. The address A1 of course still exists but now points to a different range.

You can clear a range or overwrite it with new data or copy a range from somewhere and paste it somewhere else.

BTW inserting ranges can be very time-expensive ...